# Xamarin Forms iPhone Device Details

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently with Xamarin Forms. I need to write a piece of code for a specific iPhone Version. Something like `if (iphone == 5S) then do something`.

How do i achieve this in Xamarin Studio (Forms).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin/) plugin to get the device model. A good idea is to print the device model using `Debug.WriteLine()` to see what the method returns.

```
var model = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model;
Debug.Write(model);
if (model == "MySmartPhoneModel)
{
    // Your method
}
```

Comment: -1 `CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model` just returns 'iPhone' for all iOS devices with idiom of iphone. It does not give you the exact model.

Answer (score -1):

This can also be achieved by using DependencyService.
DependencyService allows you to access Native Features.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

By using `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model`, in your iOS project, you can retrieve the model of the user's device.

Comment: -1 does not answer the question. `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model` just returns 'iPhone' for all iOS devices with idiom of iphone (i.e. not iPads).  It will not give you the exact model.